# Drupal entity with field collections not saving value to a variable

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have field collections within an entity and I'm trying to theme the values but having a hard time saving some of those values as variables. In the code below, I am trying to print the value for `'field_area_headline'` but getting an 'undefined index' notice in my browser. I've included an image of my browser where I have dpm-'d my variables that will likely be a clue for those who know what to look for.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
    <?php foreach($variables['field_focusareas'] as $delta => $item) : ?>
   <?php $focus_area_node = $item['entity']; ?>
     <?php foreach($focus_area_node->field_area as $focus_delta => $area) : ?>
     <!-- <?php dpm($area); ?> -->
     <?php $focus_area = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($area[0]['value'])); 
      dpm($focus_area);?>
      <?php $headline = $focus_area['field_area_headline'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['safe_value']; ?>
      <h3><?php print $headline; ?> </h3>
      <span></span>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image: DPM]

Answer (score 0):

`$focus_area` is an object, not an array. You need to retrieve an object property - `$headline = $focus_area->field_area_headline[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['safe_value'];`